# Get the final rendered HTML code after Javascript and ect

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio-2010

I'm using C#, and I've been struggling for a few days for grabbing the final rendered HTML from an URL.

I've tried using several browser engines, Awesomium, WebBrowser and so on, but none of them returns the actual rendered HTML of the page, as if I right clicked in chrome and chose "inspect element".

Comment: You could read on [how to ask decent questions](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jonskeet/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) in order to imrove the qualtity of your question.

Comment: Wauw. It must be really bad. Please, tell what part of it you don't understand, or what information you need.

Comment: Do you mean including any modifications made to the DOM by any scripts included in the page (i.e. invoke url, *execute the scripts*, then grab the html) ?

Comment: Yes, I need final HTML, when everything on the site has loaded.

Comment: Actually, there is no way to know when HTML manipulation has ended. A script can use (or abuse) timeout + callbacks to perform some manipulation, or rely on some AJAX call that may have its own delay. There won't be any reliable way to know when the page is "ready" (in term of usage). The less bad way is to arbitrary define a "probably ready" time (5s?) before you actually grab the HTML.

Comment: I did that, but I'm still not able to find a way to grab the current HTML, even after a timer is set, and the site is loaded visually.

Answer (score 1):

What I do is roughly the following (using the [`WebBrowser` WinForms control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser)):

```
public static string GetDomSource(WebBrowser wb)
{
    var dd = wb.Document.DomDocument as IHTMLDocument2;
    return dd.body.parentElement.outerHTML;
}
```

(Though I don't know whether you already tried this or whether you are using WinForms at all).

To introduce the `IHTMLDocument2` interface, I've add a reference to the "Microsoft.mshtml" assembly.

Comment: Seems useful, I haven't tried this yet, however, I'm getting a reference error that cannot be resolved. http://puu.sh/ddQob/1cc33c6a61.png

Comment: Oh you must have added that recently, or I've been a genius and skipped the line. Thank you.